# Hypothesis Of Fundamental Theorem Of Calculus

Tags: real-analysis

By the fundamental theorem of calculus we know that if $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ then $\int^x_af(t)dt$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$. But what if $f(x)$ is a piecewise continuous function, will the Theorem be still applicable or not. If not is there a counterexample to prove it?

Comment: Just think about the signum function.

Comment: Do you consider $f(x)=1/x$ to be piecewise continuous on $[-1,1]$? How about $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$? I.e., does your definition of piecewise continuity put any restrictions on the behavior of the function near the points of discontinuity?

Comment: The integral $F(x) =\int_{a}^{x}f(t)\,dt$ is continuous for any integrable function $f$. Also $F$ is differentiable wherever $f$ is continuous. But if $f$ is discontinuous at some point, $F$ may or may not be differentiable there.

Answer (score 1):

If by piecewise continuous you mean a function with a **finite** number of 
**[jump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Jump_discontinuity)** discontinuities then

$$
F(x) = \int\limits_a^x {f(t)dt} 
$$
is continuous on $[a,b]$ and has derivative in every point where $f(t)$ is **continuous**.

Comment: How to prove what you said above?

Comment: Try to read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus